# How do you use Python's xml library to parse the character &?

Tags: python, xml

I am running the following code, however the result I get is hiding the strings following the `&` character. Is there a way I can force walk through the children in the xml and return the proper text?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
file="/home/pi/bin/test/test_xml3.xml"
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="ascii")

root = ET.parse(file)

for elements in root.iter('kiddy'): #iterate through each element
    print elements.text
```

The example file which is causing the issue is this, specifically the result strips out the **quot;** and **amp;** strings:

```
<root>
<kiddy> shghsgdh &amp; sdjhgsjhsjdh &amp; sjhsjhdsjdh </kiddy>
<kiddy> xxxx &amp; xxxxx &amp; xxxxx </kiddy>
</root>
```

The output, as you can see, is missing the **amp;** string:

```
shghsgdh & sdjhgsjhsjdh & sjhsjhdsjdh
xxxx & xxxxx & xxxxx
```

Comment: What output do you get, and what output do you expect?

Comment: Hi, i have added the ouput, as you can see the ouput is missing the 'amp', i also tried using: elements.text.encode('ascii') but not change..... you have any idea's?

Comment: Take out the `encoding=ascii` from your code. It doesn't help with the escaped entities, and it will give you problems if there are accented characters or any other non-ascii symbols in your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amp;` is missing from your output [because](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) may appear in their literal form only when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "&amp;" and "&lt;".

Therefore, when the parser encounters `&amp;`, it parses it to be just a single `&`.

If you're truly interested in the original string, I suggest you escape the relevant section via a [`CDATA` section](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#sec-cdata-sect) (a `CDATA` section starts with `<![CDATA[` and ends with `]]>`), as follows:

```
<root>
<kiddy> shghsgdh ; sdjhgsjhsjdh ;  sjhsjhdsjdh </kiddy>
<kiddy name="All Shows" thumb="special://home/addons/plugin.video.plexbmc/resources/plex.png"><![CDATA[ActivateWindow(10025,&quot;plugin://plugin.video.plexbmc/?mode=0&amp;url=http%3a%2f%2f192.168.0.1%3a32400%2flibrary%2fsections%2f2%2fall&quot;,return)]]></kiddy>
</root>
```

[This is a link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) to a concise read on the subject.

---

To illustrate this better, I'll show you how this should look with your updated example (for completeness' sake I've added another line that includes the string `&quot;`):

```
<root>
<kiddy><![CDATA[ shghsgdh &amp; sdjhgsjhsjdh &amp; sjhsjhdsjdh ]]></kiddy>
<kiddy><![CDATA[ xxxx &amp; xxxxx &amp; xxxxx ]]></kiddy>
<kiddy><![CDATA[ xxxx &quot; xxxxx &quot; xxxxx ]]></kiddy>
</root>
```

Alternatively, you can also escape just those particular `&` character you want to, by adding the string `amp;` after each `&` character, thus creating the escaped string `&amp;` which is parsed to `&`. This can be safely followed by your original string (`amp;` or `quot;`), without fear of it being escaped, as it is not prefixed by the character `&`. I hope that an example would clarify this (imagine how each `&amp;` is parsed to the character `&`):

```
<root>
<kiddy> shghsgdh &amp;amp; sdjhgsjhsjdh &amp;amp; sjhsjhdsjdh </kiddy>
<kiddy> xxxx &amp;amp; xxxxx &amp;amp; xxxxx </kiddy>
<kiddy> xxxx &amp;quot; xxxxx &amp;quot; xxxxx </kiddy>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not that `amp;` is missing, it's that `&amp;` is the XML representation of `&`-- it's being decoded for you. If you generate XML with `ElementTree` the reverse will happen, so there's nothing to worry about-- just work with the decoded text.

But if you really need to see the XML entities in your strings for some reason, you can always edit them back in:

```
text = re.sub(r'"', r"&quot;", text)
text = re.sub(r"&", r"&amp;", text)
```

**Edit:** If you really want to re-escape the XML entities, it would be better form to use a library function, perhaps `xml.dom.minidom` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546747/699305). But I can't think of any good reason you'd need to do this; you can't even use the escaped strings if you use a library to generate XML, because the library will escape the escapes. What `ElementTree` gives you *is* ASCII (or unicode, but this has nothing to do with the entity escaping), and you should work with that.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes perfect sense, I was thinking there was a method of adjusting the output into ASCII which would solve the problem. That would have been graceful, but I see now that simply performing a replace as per your code above will work equally well. Thanks

Comment: To reiterate, what you get _is_ ascii. What you want is the original XML-encoded text. If you really do want to restore the escaped entities, search your document to see what other entities it might encode and use a python library function to re-encode them.

Comment: Note that while this works on most cases, it might perform some redundant replaces if `&` is used as a markup delimiter, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a `CDATA` section, as [`&` doesn't have any special meaning in such cases](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax), so a more sophisticated replace function might be in order. Anyway, this answer earned my up-vote nonetheless since it doesn't seem to be an issue in this case, but mainly because of the first paragraph which is missing from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26226043/3903832).

Comment: @Yoel, thanks. Adding a library-based solution when I get a chance. I'm still not sure what the use case _really_ is here, though.