# Escaping string to use in xml tags

Tags: python, xml

**Preliminary:** This is not the question that has been answered here:

[Escaping strings for use in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546717/escaping-strings-for-use-in-xml)

**The actual question:**

I have inherited an xml schema that unfortunately encodes the filename of the xml itself as an element (which is highly unusual and not a good idea, I know):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<this_actual_xml_filename.xml>
    <content>
    </content>
</this_actual_xml_filename.xml>
```

I know this is not very useful for a number of reasons, but since I can't change the structure with putting a lot of effort into a tool that uses this file, I am stuck with it for the moment. One of the reasons this is not a good idea is that filenames are much less restricted than xml element names so it is easy to imagine how problems can arise, e.g. generating an xml named `valid_filename_(but_invalid_xml).xml` would lead to this xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<valid_filename_(but_invalid_xml).xml>
    <content>
    </content>
</valid_filename_(but_invalid_xml).xml>
```

My question is whether there is a way, in Python, to escape any characters that are not allowed in xml elements. Escaping this in a somewhat transparent manner would allow me to reconstruct the original filename in the tool that reads the xml.

I could roll my own using the standard: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp but I was wondering whether there is something ready-made for an unusual case like this.

**Addendum:** Let me stress that this construct is very bad style and that it would be strongly recommended to refactor the file format instead of finding a workaround. Therefore I assume there is no ready-made solution for this problem in any library, since the construct itself goes against basic xml design guidelines.

I posted this question in case that a solution does exist, so that I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel. I will accept a simple "does not exist" as an answer if nothing else comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you anticipated, there is no existing way in Python to map from the characters allowed in a filename (for whatever OS) to characters allowed in an XML element name.  To be able to do so reversibly would be additionally challenging.

As you also acknowledge, the XML design is unconventional and problematic, for reasons that only begin with the trouble you're currently having regarding allowed characters.

Recommendations, best first:

1. Fix the problematic design, even if this means fixing upstream and downstream dependencies.
2. Pre- and/or post-process to map filenames to legal XML element names.
3. Design and implement the sort of reversible name mapping scheme you have in mind.  The level of effort here, combined with the regrettable perpetuation of previous design mistakes, makes this approach unattractive.

**See also**

- [Allowed symbols in XML element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534945/allowed-symbols-in-xml-element-name)

Comment: Thank you, that's a very helpful answer. I will re-evaluate weighing the implementation of a dirty fix (2/3) for an intermediate solution against the benefit of a more costly redesign (1) that would have to be done in the long run anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A convention I have seen used is to replace all "special" characters (for some definition of "special") by `_HHHH_` where `HHHH` is the hexadecimal character code. But I don't know of any handy library that does this for you. And it would probably be much easier to write the element out as

```
<file name="valid_filename_(but_invalid_xml).xml">
 ...
</file>
```

Comment: Your example would be the proper xml way to do this (except of course having the filename in the xml itself is not a good idea since it introduces redundancy).

Comment: Using hex values as a workaround seems a neat way if there is absolutely no option of refactoring the format, but you would have to add some markers to identify your codes in case the filenames contain these specific characters or you wouldn't be able to transform back. I thought of something like the &auml; transcriptions of xml, but since the allowed character set is very limited, there aren't a lot of good options to encode this.

Comment: Thinking more about this, I doubt there even is a way to escape the characters in a way that guarantees all possibles filenames can be converted but still get them to be converted back. The only option would be to ensure that the original filenames do not contain certain character combinations. Since this would be an emergency fix, I guess it might be possible to enforce. At this point it's more a though experiment though, since it becomes clearer and clearer that a refactoring of the format is the only way to go.

Comment: It's not difficult to devise a reversible encoding. If `_` is your escape character, just make sure that any `_` in the original string is itself treated as a special character and escaped. (I've realised that the underscores in my original answer were misinterpreted as markdown escape characters - this is getting too self-referential for comfort)

Comment: You're right of course. This works because we can assume a fixed length for the unicode characters, so we don't need a terminator. I guess I overlooked this since our filenames are already fairly long and contain a lot of underscores, so doubling them would make them even longer inside the xml. It's entirely possible though, you are correct.