Parsing XML with lxml without unescaping characters
Is there a way to read XML from a string with lxml, without converting escaped characters (&apos; for ', &quot; for ", etc) back to their original form?
For example,
from lxml import etree

def test_etree_parse():
    test_str = "Text&apos;s escaped"
    xml = etree.XML(f"<root>{test_str}</root>")
    assert xml.find(".").text == test_str

This fails because etree.XML converts "Text&apos;s escaped" to "Text's escaped".

Why would you want that? This is part of parsing XML. You can always convert it back to entities yourself if you want, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546717/escaping-strings-for-use-in-xml

@Barmar My goal is to replace part of a target system which produces XML, where strings are escaped e.g. ' >> &apos; - probably in a non-standard way, knowing the developer... lxml does not escape strings (or at least not in the same way) - it would output <root>Text's escaped</root> - so I'm doing the escaping. In my tests, I want to ingest a complete XML file from the target system, and assert my XML contains exactly the same data, including exactly the same escaping.

There's other ways to make this work e.g. transforming the test XML after parsing it, customising xmldiff possibly (or just not having '"<>& or characters beyond codepoint 127 in the test data)... but I hoped there's a simple "leave strings verbatim" option for the etree parser I've failed to find

In general, software that parses a data format doesn't usually provide any way to return the raw input data. It converts it to a canonical representation of the data.
